# angular checkbox does not bind to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, data-binding

In my controller I have this member:

```
$scope.sameOptionsOnReturn = true;
```

and in my view:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="sameOptionsOnReturn"
       ng-checked="sameOptionsOnReturn"
       ng-value="true"
       ng-change="setReturnOptions" />
```

But the input does not bind to the checkbox; it's always true. What is wrong?

**Note:** removing `ng-value="true"` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Try removing `ng-value="true"`.

Comment: @Tushar - didn't make any difference I'm afraid

Comment: Try this: <input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="sameOptionsOnReturn"
       ng-checked="sameOptionsOnReturn = !sameOptionsOnReturn"
       ng-change="setReturnOptions()" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it does work in the snippet below, I have to assume there's something wrong elsewhere in your code.

```js
function SuperController($scope) {
 $scope.sameOptionsOnReturn = true;
}

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('SuperController', SuperController)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SuperController as s">
    <input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="sameOptionsOnReturn"
       ng-checked="sameOptionsOnReturn"
       ng-value="true"
       ng-change="setReturnOptions" />
    
    {{sameOptionsOnReturn}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-model works for your bindings . So you don`t need to put ng-value="true" which making your checkbox always checked .remove it from the input checkbox . ng-model value will make your checkbox checked or unchecked .

Comment: didn't make any difference I'm afraid